# Keras convolution 1D channel indepently, [samples,timesteps,features] , wind turbine dataset

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, convolution

I'm  working on a wind turbine dataset which has a regular matrix format: [ row:datetime , column:features]

But I want to capture with convolution the progress of each of this features like is done in LSTM. So, I have generated a new dataset with the following dimensions:

[datetime, 15 timesteps,128 features] : Each original datetime row now has 15 registers concatenated (t-0,t-1,...,t-14) for each feature.

My plan is to convolute in the timestep dimension for each feature (channel) separately with a kernel of size 1x5 and stride of 5. Getting for each DateTime(batch), 3 filters of length 5 from the 128 features, the output shape is (None,3,128).

Then I apply max-pooling to the previous second dimension (3) result, in order to get "the most important convoluted timestep" expecting the output size: (None,1,128)

And finally I connect a dense layer for binary classification.

The current network architecture is implemented in keras as follows:

```python
model.add( Conv1D(padding = 'valid',filters = nfeatures,strides = 5,kernel_size = 5, 
                  activation = 'relu',input_shape = (timesteps,nfeatures)) )
model.add( MaxPooling1D() )
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

The problem is when I check the weights at the first layer (conv1d) the weights have the following dimensions:  [5,128,128] and the bias [128].

The expected weights format is : [5,1,128] why is 5x128x128? ,I want only 5 weights (kernel size) for each feature/channel.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Standard convolution filers:**

In order to have great results, neural nets rarely consider a feature completely alone, on the contrary, they promote the correlations between features to extract smarter results.

That's why the standard convolution filter shapes are:

```
(width, input_features, output_features)
```

In this convolution, all the input features are considered to create new output features.

**How to completely individualize features?**

> warning: this uses the same exact filter for all features (you may want one individual filter per feature, then see the next answer)

You can reorder your data so the features become a major group, and make each group have only one feature and filter.

These groups can be then processed inparallel with the `TimeDistributed` layer.

```py
model = Sequential()

#reordering data and adding 1 dummy feature per group    
model.add(Permute((2,1), input_shape = (timesteps,nfeatures))) #(batch, feat, steps)    
model.add(Lambda(lambda x: K.expand_dims(x))) #(batch, feat, steps, 1)

#applying the 1 filter convolution for each group
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv1D(padding = 'valid',filters = 1,strides = 5,
                                 kernel_size = 5, activation = 'relu')))
model.add( TimeDistributed(MaxPooling1D()) )

#restoring to (batch,features)    
model.add(Reshape((nfeatures,)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

Honestly, your model will be way more powerful using the standard convolution, but you may have special reasons for doing this.

**One individual filter per feature**

This requires more work. We will need either a custom layer that implements a depthwise_conv1d (which Keras doesn't offer), or we create 128 individual conv1D layers with 1 filter (easier).

Using the second approach (muliple conv layers), we will need a functional API model to make parallel brances.

```py
from keras.model import Model

#function to split the input in multiple outputs
def splitter(x):
    return [x[:,:,i:i+1] for i in range(nfeatures)]


#model's input tensor 
inputs = Input((timesteps,nfeatures))

#splitting in 128 parallel tensors - 128 x (batch,15,1)
multipleFeatures = Lambda(splitter)(inputs)

#applying one individual convolution on each parallel branch
multipleFeatures = [
   Conv1D(padding = 'valid',filters = 1,strides = 5, kernel_size = 5)(feat) 
   for feat in multipleFeatures ]

#joining the branches into (batch, 3, 128)
joinedOutputs = Concatenate()(multipleFeatures)
joinedOutputs = Activation('relu')(joinedOutputs)

outputs = MaxPooling1D()(joinedOutputs)
outputs = Lambda(lambda x: K.squeeze(x,axis=1))(outputs)
outputs = Dropout(0.5)(outputs)
outputs = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(outputs)

model = Model(inputs,outputs)
```

Comment: Read the problem again. I have the data entries at the rows and the features at the columns. I want to capture a progression of the different features in 15 timesteps, this is why each original row has a lag of 15(copy of t-0 to t-15) in the second dimension.

Comment: Fixed my answer with two possibilities. Using the same filter for all features or using an individual filter for each feature.

Comment: Thanks for your nice edit! Your help is much appreciated!

I will give a try to your first solution. The second solution is not the current keras 2.1.6 [SeparableConv1D](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#separableconv1d)?

I'm separating the convolutions in layers, first dedicated to timesteps without combine channels (features) because I would like to see the importance of the different features evolution on the first layer and then If it works I will add an additional convolution layer (this time to combine features/channels) to capture the "correlations".

Comment: The concept of SeparableConv is different. It separates the kernels in two, one depth and another length. One of its steps is the Depthwise convolution indeed, but there is another step that will collapse the depth.

Comment: There is in the backend the `depthwise_conv2d`, which does what you want, but only for 4D data. It misses the `depthwise_conv1D`, although you could also make your data `(batch, 1, timesteps, nfeatures)` and use a kernel size `(1,5)`. But you would need to create a custom layer (to enable trainable filters) and use this function inside it.